# My Jquery code working fine in desktop browser but not working in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I have a page in which i am using jquery to hide show and modal box open close. It is working fine desktop browser but not working in mobile browser. Even when i open it in responsive screen of browser it is working fine.Please help me to solve this problem and there is no error showing in console. here is my jquery code. Thanks in advance.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs').tabs({
      swipeable : true,
      responsiveThreshold : 1920
    });
  });
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form").hide();
        $(".save-form").hide();
        $(".edit-form").click(function() {
            $("#detail").hide(200);
            $("#form").show(200);
            $(".edit-form").hide();
            $(".save-form").show();
        });
        $(".save-form").click(function() {
            $("#detail").show(200);
            $("#form").hide(200);
            $(".edit-form").show();
            $(".save-form").hide();
        });
        $('.datepicker').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
            selectYears: 200, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
            today: 'Today',
            clear: 'Clear',
            close: 'Ok',
            closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
        });
        $('.start-college').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
            selectYears: 100, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
            today: 'Today',
            clear: 'Clear',
            close: 'Ok',
            closeOnSelect: true // Close upon selecting a date,
        });
        $('.end-college').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
            selectYears: 100, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
            today: 'Today',
            clear: 'Clear',
            close: 'Ok',
            closeOnSelect: true // Close upon selecting a date,
        });
        $('input.gender').autocomplete({
            data: {
                "Male": null,
                "Female": null
            },
            limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
            onAutocomplete: function(val) {
                // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
            },
            minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
        });
        $('input.college').autocomplete({
            data: {
                "PSIT": null,
                "PSIT COE": null,
                "KIT": null
            },
            limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
            onAutocomplete: function(val) {
                // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
            },
            minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
        });
        $('input.city').autocomplete({
            data: {
                "Kanpur": null,
                "Jaipur": null
            },
            limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
            onAutocomplete: function(val) {
                // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
            },
            minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
        });
        $('input.field').autocomplete({
            data: {
                "Information Technology": null,
                "Computer Science": null
            },
            limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
            onAutocomplete: function(val) {
                // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
            },
            minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
        });
        $('input.degree').autocomplete({
            data: {
                "B.TECH": null,
                "BSc": null,
                "B.COM": null
            },
            limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
            onAutocomplete: function(val) {
                // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
            },
            minLength: 1, // The minimum length of the input for the autocomplete to start. Default: 1.
        });
        $('#textarea1').val('New Text');
        $('#textarea1').trigger('autoresize');




    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
        $('.modal').modal();
    });
```

Comment: why do you use $(document).ready() so many time.Write it once and the add all the code that relies to $(document).ready()

Comment: did that still not working.

Comment: only working in web browser

Comment: when debug it via chrome on mobile i get this error -> Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

Comment: and this -> [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 337ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 63ms
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3 [Violation] Handling of 'touchstart' input event was delayed for 2147483647 ms due to main thread being busy. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

Comment: Once i remove swipeable : true, from tabs its working fine. now how can i handle that ?